# System.getConsol() returns null when using gradlew run

Tags: java, gradle, console

My Java application needs to prompt the user for a password. In order to do that (and in order to maintain security) we are using `System.getConsole().readPassword().`

However when starting the application via `gradlew clean run` System.getConsole() returns null.

This is my application

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
       Console CONSOLE = System.console();
       if (CONSOLE == null) {
         System.err.println("No console.");
         System.exit(1);
       }
       char[] password = CONSOLE.readPassword(consoleMessage);
  }
```

And this is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.emc.ia.main.impl.PasswordEncryptor"
```

If anyone can offer any assistance it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: are you using any IDE?

Comment: No just command line